# print values returned from select..where in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select rows from table "students" where username=name from php file.
How I can print the rows returned ?? 
I used this but the values not printed (no results appears )

```
$result=mysql_query("select name from students where name=$name);


if($result){

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo " $row['name'];
}
}
```

Comment: but when removing "where" condition , it works

Comment: What PHP editor are you using? Can it color code/syntax highlight your  code?

Comment: @SalmanA
I'm using Dream weaver , yes , it colors codes.

Comment: My problem is not in selecting the required rows. It selects them , but not printing them

Comment: Did you post the code as-is? If so, you need glasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("select name from students where name='$name'");


if($result){

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['name'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `$name` is not numeric, MySQL will think it is a column and the column probably does not exist so you will get an error because of that.  Put quotes around it like `'$name'`.  You should also call `mysql_real_escape_string` on `$name` first, and you should check that the result of `mysql_query` is not `false` (if it is, check `mysql_error`).

You're also missing some quotes.

---

Even better, stop using [`ext/mysql`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) and use PDO instead.  Then you can write the query like

```
select name from students where name = ?
```

and the escaping and quote additions are done automatically for you.

Comment: +1  better answer than mine ..

Answer (score 1):

if you use string use quote other wise it will treat as column name

```
$result=mysql_query("select name from students where name='$name'");
```

---

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result=mysql_query("select name from students where name='$name'");
```

And `echo " $row['name'];` should be `echo $row['name'];`

Comment: Sorry ," $row['name'] I wrote this  by accedent, also , '$name' with quetes did not work either